$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{N}\sum\limits^N_{k=1}f(k\gamma)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ for irrational $\gamma$ and continuous function with period $1$
The problem is stated below:

Problem: If $\gamma$ is a irrational number, $f$ is a periodic continuous real-valued function with period $1$, then $$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\dfrac{f(\gamma)+f(2\gamma)+\cdots+f(N\gamma)}{N}=\int_0^1 f(x)dx.$$

In fact, I want to solve the problem by steps below.
Step 1. For any non-zero integer $k$, we have $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^Ne^{2\pi i k\cdot n\gamma}=0.$$
Step 2. (The hint of the problem) For continuous function $f$, its Cesaro sum $\sigma_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits^n_{k=0}S_k(x)$, which converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.


My attempt: Since $S_n(x)=\sum\limits^n_{k=-n}F_ke^{2\pi ikx}$, where $$F_{k}=\int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2\pi i kx}dx,$$ Step 1 may imply that $F_k$ vanishes for $k\neq 0$, and $F_0=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is the right side of the equation.

But I don't know the relationship between the left side of the equation and the cesaro sum $\sigma_n$. Can you give me some advice?

Let $\mathcal D$ be the set of functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ of the form
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^n a_k e^{2\pi i k x}, \quad a_k \in \mathbb C,\; n \geq 0.$$
For functions $f \in \mathcal D$, by linearity we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{f(\gamma) + \cdots + f(N\gamma)}{N} = a_0 = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.$$
So, for a general continuous 1-periodic function $f$, let $\sigma_n$ to be the $n$-th Cesaro sum of $f$. We can see that $\sigma_n \in \mathcal D$ for each $n\geq 1$, so that
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sigma_n(\gamma) + \cdots + \sigma_n(N\gamma)}{N} = \int_0^1 \sigma_n(x)\,dx.$$
Now, for $\epsilon > 0$, one can choose $n$ large enough that $|\sigma_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Since $f$ and $\sigma_n$ are 1-periodic, the estimate will hold for $x\in \mathbb R$. Applying the reverse triangle inequality shows:
$$-2\epsilon + \left|\frac{\sigma_n(\gamma) + \cdots + \sigma_n(N\gamma)}{N} - \int_0^1 \sigma_n(x)\,dx\right| \leq \left|\frac{f(\gamma) + \cdots + f(N\gamma)}{N} - \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right| \leq \left|\frac{\sigma_n(\gamma) + \cdots + \sigma_n(N\gamma)}{N} - \int_0^1 \sigma_n(x)\,dx\right| + 2\epsilon.$$
Keep $n$ fixed, and take $N\to \infty$ using the limsup and liminf. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary you can conclude.
